# How do I change the name of an XML tag in Hy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, hy

This is my first post here...

I am trying to change an XML element using [assignment](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#changing-tag-names-and-attributes) in Hy (running on Python 3).

When I try to run the code snippet:

```
(setv tco (BeautifulSoup "<meek/>" 'xml))
(setv (. tco meek name) "defl")
(print (. tco meek name))
;(assoc (. tco defl) "new" "value")
(.append (. tco meek) "Kool Stuff")
(print (.prettify tco))
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/hy", line 9, in
>   
>       load_entry_point('hy==0.11.0', 'console_scripts', 'hy')()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 347, in hy_main
>       sys.exit(cmdline_handler("hy", sys.argv))   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 335, in
>   cmdline_handler
>       return run_file(options.args[0])   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 210, in run_file
>       import_file_to_module("**main**", filename)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hy/importer.py", line 78, in
>   import_file_to_module
>       eval(ast_compile(_ast, fpath, "exec"), mod.**dict**)   File "code-trace.hy", line 196, in 
>       (setv (. tco meek name) "defl") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Running with the second line commented:

```
(setv tco (BeautifulSoup "<meek/>" 'xml))
;(setv (. tco meek name) "defl")
(print (. tco meek name))
;(assoc (. tco defl) "new" "value")
(.append (. tco meek) "Kool Stuff")
(print (.prettify tco))
```

Gives no error (had to mark using code instead of blockquote so it shows properly):

```
meek
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<meek>
 Kool Stuff
</meek>
```

Note that this is just some test code for a larger program. I am also having problems with the commented [assoc](http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html#assoc) on the 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird one! It looks like changing the name makes (. tco meek) become None, which indeed has no name attribute. So you have to catch that error. Then you have to refer to (. tco defl) because that is how it is known after the assignment. This works.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC hy
(import [bs4 [BeautifulSoup]])

(setv tco (BeautifulSoup "<meek/>" 'xml))
(try (setv (. tco meek name) "defl") (except [e Exception] (print e)))
(print (. tco defl))
(assoc (. tco defl) "new" "value")
(.append (. tco defl) "Kool Stuff")
(print (.prettify tco))

#+END_SRC
#+RESULTS:
: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
: <defl/>
: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
: <defl new="value">
:  Kool Stuff
: </defl>
```

If you look at the Python that hy generates:

```
#+begin_example
from hy import HySymbol
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tco = BeautifulSoup(u'<meek/>', HySymbol(u'xml'))
try:
    tco.meek.name = u'defl'
    _hy_anon_var_1 = tco.meek.name
except Exception as e:
    _hy_anon_var_1 = print(e)
print(tco.defl)
tco.defl[u'new'] = u'value'
tco.defl.append(u'Kool Stuff')
print(tco.prettify())
#+end_example
```

You can see the error in this line: _hy_anon_var_1 = tco.meek.name. I guess tco.meek.name doesn't exist after the line before it is run, so you get the error. I don't know why hy would expand that way, it seems to be related to the use of (. ) in the code, because other setv expressions don't expand that way.